# trying to figure out how to use App Switcher on Lion

Tags: application-switcher, mouse

I recently bought a used Mighty Mouse, the slightly older kind with a little button on top that scrolls. (could anyone tell me what to call this button?)

I set the button to use the App Switcher, which I had never used before.

App Switcher opens okay, no problem there. and I can go left and right between them. but I can't actually open or switch to the app or, for that matter, close them. I *can* use App Switcher using the keyboard, though, thanks to tutorials. but I can't figure out how to do it with the mouse.

so how I can actually *use* App Switcher using the mouse? FYI, I use 10.8.4.

Comment: Mind telling us which version of OS X are you using?

Comment: no, I don't mind. 10.8.4.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Mouse System Preference. There is a setting for each button on the mouse - including the nipple like one on the top. On my iMac I have this set to Off, but there is an option for Application Switcher, which if you chose that it would allow you to switch application by clicking the nipple button. I just tried this and it works, though I might not leave things set this way. If you don't like the idea of a nipple button, it's also called a mini mouse button. Oh, I'm using Mountain Lion too

Comment: this does not answer my question. I know how to assign different functions to different parts of the mouse. 

but re-read the third paragraph. I can open App Switcher and I can make a square frame appear around apps, but I cannot figure out how to actually switch between apps (or close them, for that matter).